# Count object in array in each element

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection of persons in mongodb. 
    A list of persons and each person has an array of language used

```
{ 
    "name" : "dev1", 
    "languages": [
        " java", 
        " python"
    ]
}
{ 
    "name" : "dev2", 
    "languages" : [
        "java", 
        "javascript"
    ]
}

I try to count the language used by the person, according to this JSON, the final output result expected will be :

{
    "java": 2,
    "python":1,
    "javascript": 1
}

Any idea to get that result with a mongoDB query ?

Many thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a typo in your question and the values in your arrays do not contain any additional spaces. Then you can get what you want using

```
collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$languages" // flatten the "languages" array
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$languages", // group all occurrences of the same language into a bucket
        "count": { $sum: 1 } // count the occurrences per bucket
    }
})
```

This gives you the following result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "javascript",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "python",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "java",
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

You can add quite some complex transformation steps at the end to get the exact output you want but I would doubt that it's worth it:

```
collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$languages" // flatten the "languages" array
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$languages",
        "count": { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null, // group by hardcoded _id in order to merge all documents
        "temp": { $push: { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } } // create an array that matches the structure that the $arrayToObject stage expects
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        temp: {
            $arrayToObject: "$temp" // transform key value pair array into object
        }
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$temp" } // replace root element with our final result
})
```

This will give you:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "javascript" : 1.0,
    "python" : 1.0,
    "java" : 2.0
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! It s exactly what I need